# PHP or Jquery Library code that outputs a section of a webpage to a PDF file

Tags: php, jquery, pdf-generation, mpdf

I need to find and use a PHP or Javascript library or plugin that can output my html code to a pdf. I have seen libraries such as MPDF, FPDF have a number of limitations, for instance the above mentioned libraries dont render svg elements and charts.
I am currently using MPDF to render html tables nicely but I also have charts and maps on my webpage being output dynamically using Jquery and some other svg elements.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use external program to render PDF from HTML(used it with PHP and Ruby)  called wkhtmltopdf which renders any HTML using WebKit(with styles, scripts etc) and allows you generate output PDF file. Since it support SVG i  think that should be displayed in PDF - but better to use more recent versions because there could be some unsupported features in older one.

```
system('/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf input.html output.pdf');
```

You of course can control some options like page orientation and size using arguments

Comment: I will definately check out wkhtmltopdf but i dont think users  - website users -- will be okay with installing another desktop application to be able download a pdf document from a web page. I think its too much for them. I will keep looking  - or maybe create my own!

Comment: They do not need to - you render PDF on backend from PHP code on your server(first build HTML then as i said generate resuling PDF from that HTML). There is also static build for servers where you can't compile binary. Good part of using this is that you can use JS, embed images, charts etc etc

Comment: @Hey Alexander N -- i am facing some difficulty with the wkhtmlpdf converter - the CMD conversion was successful - now its the phpwkhtmlpdf with some complexity...